# Android-Override method to handle onClick and Swipe gestures

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener, ontouchlistener

I am using a library to implement a ListView with Swipe to Dismiss function. 
I would like to know how to intercept the event before calling the custom listener from the library to handle the onClick event in a view from the ListView. 
Or how could override the OnTouch method to handle the Click event.

Here is the [SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations/blob/master/library/src/com/haarman/listviewanimations/itemmanipulation/SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener.java) from the library.
I know that I have to do somenthing with the `case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:`, but everything I tried went wrong. If I consume the Click on `case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:` it doenst alow anymore the swipe gesture. If I consume the Click on `case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:` it doenst work to, just the Swipe.

Here is a [example](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations/blob/master/example/src/com/haarman/listviewanimations/GoogleCardsActivity.java) of a Activity very similiar to that I implemented.
In this case I want to be able to do something like `view.setOnClickListener` in the method `public void getView` without it block the Swipe Gesture

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a fairly old post, but I had a problem with this as well, so I am posting how I solved it.

First off, I created a class that implemented OnTouchListener. The class records the position of where the user first presses the screen, and then records the position of when the user lifts finger off the screen. If the distance between the two points was greater than 200px, then I notify the listening view that the user swiped left or right, otherwise, I notify the listener that the user clicked the view.

Here is the class:

```
 public class SmartLinkSwipeDetector implements OnTouchListener {

     //declare needed constants
     private final String CLASS_NAME = getClass().getName();

     private final int MIN_DISTANCE = 200; //TODO - change distance
     private float downX, upX;

     //declare needed variables
     private SmartLinkSwipeDetectorInterface swipeDetector;

     public SmartLinkSwipeDetector(WorkoutSupplementBaseFragment fragment) {
          super();
         testForSwipeDetectorInterface(fragment);
     }

     private void testForSwipeDetectorInterface(WorkoutSupplementBaseFragment fragment) {
         //ensure activity implements interface
         try {
              swipeDetector = (SmartLinkSwipeDetectorInterface) fragment;
         } catch (ClassCastException ex) {
              String errorString = fragment.getClass().getName() + " must implement   SmartLinkSwipeDetectorInterface";
             Log.e(CLASS_NAME, errorString);
             throw new ClassCastException(errorString);
         }
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
          switch (event.getAction()) {

               case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    downX = event.getX();
                    return true;

               case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    upX = event.getX();
                    float deltaX = downX - upX;

                    if (Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE) {
                         if (deltaX < 0)
                              swipeDetector.swipeRight();
                         else if (deltaX > 0)
                              swipeDetector.swipeLeft();
                    } else {
                         swipeDetector.onShortClick(view);
               }

                    return true;

               default:
                    return true;
         }
     }
 }
```

Make sure that the activity or fragment using this OnTouchListener implements an interface similar to this one:

```
 public interface SmartLinkSwipeDetectorInterface {

      public void onShortClick(View view);

      public void swipeLeft();

      public void swipeRight();

  }
```

Lastly, any view or button that wants to implement this OnTouchListener needs to do it like this:

```
 View.setOnTouchListener(new SmartLinkSwipeDetector(this));
```

Where this is an activity or fragment that implements SmartLinkSwipeDetectorInterface